# Awk to exclude the heading line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following output:

```
Course: StudentCount
    ('BCA_27', 2L)
    ('MCA_34', 15L)
    ('BBA_26', 3L)
    ('BBM_02', 14L)
    ('MBA_23', 13L)
```

I am using the following command to remove unwanted characters from this:

```
<output> |sed "s/['()]//g;s/,/:/g;s/\([0-9]\)L[ ]*$/\1/g;"|awk '{print $NF,$0}' | sort -nr | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Now output is:

```
MCA_34 : 15
BBM_02 : 14
MBA_23 : 13
BBA_26 : 3
BCA_27 : 2
Course : StudentCount
```

How should I prevent `awk` to exclude the heading line so that output is :

```
Course : StudentCount
MCA_34 : 15
BBM_02 : 14
MBA_23 : 13
BBA_26 : 3
BCA_27 : 2
```

Comment: Simple, yet effective fix: `sed ... | awk 'NR==1{print 9999,$0} NR>1{print $NF,$0}' | sort ...`. But in general, I would do the whole thing in `awk` only.

Answer (score 1):

You never need sed when you're using awk:

```
$ awk -F"[',: ]+" -v OFS=' : ' '{print (NR>1) "\t" (NR==1 ? $1 OFS $2 : $3 OFS $4+0)}' file |
    sort -k1,1n -k4,4nr | cut -f2-
Course : StudentCount
MCA_34 : 15
BBM_02 : 14
MBA_23 : 13
BBA_26 : 3
BCA_27 : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tail to skip a specific number of header lines here is an example:

```bsh
command | awk  '{print $1}' | tail +2
```

this will skip the first 2 lines after performing awk on the first field of the command result.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the suggestion that [pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/236063/plumo) gave in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602592/awk-to-exclude-the-heading-line#comment1124245_602592) and making it a bit more flexible, you can change the AWK command into:

```sh
awk 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} {print $NF,$0; if ($NF>m) m=$NF} END {print (m+1),h}'
```

The idea is to guarantee that the header will be prepended with a higher number than any other line, recording the maximum value over the whole input data and only printing the header after the last line has been processed.

Alternatively, if your system supports the `/dev/fd/n` type of file descriptor links, you can duplicate the standard output of the whole pipeline and let `awk` print the header line to the new file descriptor, preventing it from going through the subsequent commands:

```sh
sed "s/['()]//g;s/,/:/g;s/\([0-9]\)L[ ]*$/\1/g;" |
  { awk 'NR == 1 {print >("/dev/fd/3"); next} {print $NF,$0}' |
  sort -nr |
  cut -f2- -d' '; } 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess the input stored in file named file using sed then via process substitution feed sed's output to `head-n-sort` commands.

```
{ head -n 1; sort -k3,3nr -k1,1; }  < <(< file sed -Ee "y/(;',)/ ; : /;s/\s+//g;1!s/L$//;s/:/ & /")
Course : StudentCount
MCA_34 : 15
BBM_02 : 14
MBA_23 : 13
BBA_26 : 3
BCA_27 : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by sed scripting:

```
sed  -e '1d' -e  '2,$s/[^A-Z_0-9]/ /g' -r  -e 's/\s+/;/g' -e 's/^;//g'  -e 's/[A-Z];$//g' filename
```

output

```
BCA_27;2
MCA_34;15
BBA_26;3
BBM_02;14
MBA_23;13
```